# sql server save transaction

Tags: sql-server, transactions, sql-server-2012

I have following code:

```
DECLARE @D INT = 1

PRINT @D
BEGIN TRANSACTION

SAVE TRANSACTION asd
SET @D = @D+1
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION asd


COMMIT TRANSACTION
PRINT @D
```

the result is :

```
1
2
```

I expect that the result should be:

```
1
1
```

what's wrong?

thanks in advance.

Comment: SQL Server variables assignments are not "protected" by transactions - only table operations like insert, updates, deletes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Databases are aimed to maintain data and the data is stored inside tables . The transactions are made to maintain data to make activities atomic inside database.Transactions only works on activities related to the tables like insert,update and delete in order to make it atomic.In your query you worked on variables and transaction not support rollback on variables because there is no data change inside database.
Also take care about temp tables and table variables . Transaction rollback work on temp table and not work on table variables. 
So your query is true and engine does its work.